# как изменить размер QImage в PyQt5 если виджет QImage уже на экране?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как изменить размер `QImage` в *PyQt5*, если виджет `QImage` уже на экране?

Я решил создать небольшой фото редактор и у меня возникла проблема - 
как изменить размер `QImage` если оно уже отрисовано?

Я пытался перезадать значение `self.image` (моего изображения), но скрипт просто закрывался.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = QImage(QSize(1000, 1000), QImage.Format_RGB32)  # Делаем холст
        self.image.fill(Qt.white)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
        self.image.size = QSize(100, 100)  # здесь я хочу что бы
        # размер изображения изменился, но незнаю как это сделть
        self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы вам дали какой-нибудь совет, опубликуйте минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Это просто пример того чего я хочу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не понимаю для чего вам это надо, но то, что вы хотите работает.
Покликайте в окошке приложения в разных места.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.w, self.h = 1366, 706                                       # +++
#        self.image = QImage(QSize(1000, 1000), QImage.Format_RGB32)  
#        self.image.fill(Qt.white)
        self.image = QImage(QSize(self.w, self.h), QImage.Format_RGB32)  # +++
        self.image.fill(qRgb(255, 000, 255))                             # +++

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
#        self.image.size = QSize(100, 100)  # здесь я хочу что бы
        # размер изображения изменился, но незнаю как это сделть
        self.w, self.h = event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()                # +++
        self.update()

# +++ Событие рисования - это запрос на перерисовку всего или части виджета.
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)        
        painter.drawImage(QRect(0, 0, self.w, self.h), self.image, QRect(0, 0, self.w, self.h)) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]